# Jquery Cannot get this element to be added before a div in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on adding an element to a static form using jquery.  When I click on submit nothing happens.  The interesting thing is when I replace submit event with click event I get the hello to flash but it disappear on the mouse release

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var addpiece = $("<p>hello</p>");
    $("#testbutton").submit(function(){
        $("#beforediv").before(addpiece);
    });
}
)  
</script>

<body>

   <div>
     <form>
      <input type="submit" id="testbutton" value="put it before" />
      <br />
      <div id="beforediv">
          <p>put before this</p>
     </div>

     </form>

    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Use `$('form').submit` instead of `$("#testbutton").submit`. You are submitting the form, not the button :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(function(){
    var addpiece = $("<p>hello</p>");
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $("#beforediv").before(addpiece);
    });
});
```

To handle a form submitting you should use `$('form_element').submit()` instead of `$('submitElement').submit()`, because you submit the **form**, not the **button**

Comment: How do I make sure it is acting on the right submit button.

Comment: I think your form has one submit button? No matter which button is clicked (of course, it should be **inside** the form and to have `type=submit`). Just when a submit button inside the `<form>` tag is clicked, the function will be called.

Comment: you should probably only one button with type=submit

Comment: Now this issue is this.  Once I do click on the submit button the element does not stay on the page.  It disappears when I release the button.